# How to configure persistence.xml in Java project (without Spring) to use the cleardb_database_url in heroku

Tags: java, heroku, persistence.xml, cleardb

I need advise how to configure persistence.xml in Java web project (without Spring) to use the cleardb_database_url so I could deploy succesffuly my database application to Heroku. I have found at Heroku site documentation how to use xml for configuring Spring, I even implemented that code to my persistence.xml but it didn't help.

I hope somebody can help me in configuring persistence.xml.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards, Sandra

Comment: Post some example code you've tried so far. This way is hard to help you..

Comment: You need to reset your db password now that you've posted it publicly (or destroy and recreate it)